Intuition behind a double integral result
I'm self learning from Jay Cummings' Real Analysis book. Exercise 8.29 (b) asks to prove that, if $f$ is continuous, then $$\int_0^x f(t)(x-t)dt = \int_0^x\left(\int_0^tf(s)ds\right)dt.$$
I've done it using algebra; If we let $F(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt$, then
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^x f(t)(x-t)dt &= x\int_0^xf(t)dt - \int_0^xtf(t)dt \\ 
&= xF(x) - \left(xF(x) - \int_0^xF(t) dt\right) \text{(Integration by Parts)}\\
&= \int_0^x\left(\int_0^tf(s)ds\right)dt.
\end{aligned}$$
However, I still don't see why the result is true at all. Is there a meaning behind the $xF(x)$'s cancelling out? This is the first time I've seen the same variable in both the bounds and the integrand (on the left hand side), and this is also the first time I've seen an integral inside an integral (on the right hand side), so I really have no intuition behind what either represent. So my question is, what do the left and right hand side 'represent', or what is a good way to think about them?
I tried to think about just the integrand of both sides; I thought of $f(t)(x-t)$ as "the value of $f$ scaled by how close the input is to $x$" but I can't see how this has anything to do with $\int_0^tf(s)ds$. Is this the right way to think about it?

Double integrals represent volumes. This result here is used in differential equations.

Not sure if this will help, but have a look at this video: https://youtu.be/jNpKKDekS6k?si=3YOAiB-OxZtBgMFK. It explains Cauchy's formula for repeated integration, which I think is related to your question, in a very nice and visual way. It may help provide the intuition for why the statement you provided should be true.

This is volume of the region bounded above by $z=f(v)$ and lying over the triangle $T=\{(u,v): 0\le v\le u, \ 0\le u\le x\}$ in the $uv$~plane. (I cannot use the usual $x,y$ coordinates because $x$ is reserved as the upper limit of the integral.)
The single integral represents the volume computed by integrating cross-sectional areas. The cross-section at fixed $v=t$ is a rectangle with base $x-t$ and height $f(t)$.
